# divide the amount of a advanced custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field with the `advanced-custom-fields` plugin. Now I want to get and output the custom field in 4 column.
For example I import:
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

but show these in 4 column

In column 1: aaa

In column 2: bbb

In column 3: ccc

In column 4: ddd

Comment: When you say column 1, is this a repeater field that you are using? Also, can you show what code you have tried so far?

Comment: no it's not a repeater field. it's a text field.

Comment: if you want to just split a string into its different parts you should look at the php explode() function

Comment: how I can split a string into its different parts in wordpress with advanced custom field?